# Update / Install CocoaPods for specific target

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podfile

Is it possible to do `pod install @targetName`?
I stuck with a problem that I do not have an option to update pods for my project but I have to install new pods for my unit tests target.

Answer (score 5):

I don´t think there is any `pod update @targetName` command in CocoaPods. What you can do is to add the desired pod in your unit test target only and then run a `pod update`, since there is not any changes in the other targets then they will not be affected by this update.

And if you add targets after you have made your `pod init` you can just append these targets to your podfile, like this:

```
  target 'ANewTargetAdded' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'SomePOD'
  end
```

If you now add a new pod to `ANewTargetAdded` and run `pod update`, then this will only affect `ANewTargetAdded` if you haven´t made any changes to your other targets in your `podfile`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any like `pod update @targetName` but you can specify different pods for different targets and unit tests and run `pod update`.

Something like this.

```
target 'TestProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestProject

  target 'TestProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'TestProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```